# How to send information back to the Front end, AFTER functions triggered by a webhook are ran?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, webhooks

I'm using Plaid API to gather transaction data from registered users. Essentially Plaid needs to retrieval updates to our webhook endpoint to let the server know when data is ready to pull. When the desired code is sent from Plaid to that endpoint, we'll know that the transaction data is ready to retrieve, our backend and will start inserting it into our database.

The problem we've run into is how to send that data to the front end. Since we're only alerted of when the data is ready to pull from Plaid on out webhook endpoint, any res.send will just go to Plaid. And if we have another endpoint to get the newly inserted data, The user would be able to hit that one before the Webhook actions take place.

We're kinda stuck. We can get the webhook to trigger the actions we need to trigger, but sending it back to the user once they've been triggered is another issue. Is there anyway to have our third endpoint wait on the second to finished before sending data back to the frontend?

This is enpoint 1, it triggers Plaid to send the their webhook to out webhook endpoint.

```
router.post('/token_exchange', publicTokenExists, async (req, res) => {
  const {publicToken} = req.body;
  const {userid} = req.body;

  try {
    const {access_token} = await client.exchangePublicToken(publicToken);

    const Accessid = await qs.add_A_Token(access_token, userid);

    const {item} = await client.getItem(access_token);

    const Itemid = await qs.add_An_Item(item.item_id, userid);

    res.status(201).json({
      accessCreated: Accessid,
      ItemCreated:Itemid
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('access', err);
  }
});
```

This is endpoint 2, out webhook endpoint. First Plaid sends a post request with an object that we ignore because the webhook_code is not the one we want the action to run on. the second one passed the conditional below

```
router.post('/webhook', async (req,res)=>{
  const body = req.body;
  console.log("THE WEBHOOK BRUH",body)

  if(body.webhook_code==="HISTORICAL TRANSACTIONS"){
    const A_token = await  qs.GetAccessTokenThatsConnectedTo(body.item_id)

    const {transactions} = await client.getTransactions(A_token)

        const done = Promise.all(
        transactions.map(async trans => {
        const contents = await qs.insert_transactions(trans);
        return trans;
      }),
    );

  }
```

This is endpoint 3, it is where our React-front-end is requesting our database for the transactions.

```
router.post('/transactions',checkAccessToken, async (req,res)=>{

  console.log("the request body", req.body)

  const access = req.body.access

  try{

const {transactions} = await qs.getTransactionsDataBaseThatWeInsertedInFunctiontwo
(access,'2019-01-01','2019-01-30')

res.status(200).json({transactions})
  }catch(err){
console.log(err)
res.status(500).json({message:"error sending transactions"})
  }

})
```

So I guess I'm looking for either solution:

Is it possible to send the inserted transaction data once completed in method 2?

Is it possible to have method 3 wait until method 2 finishes, I was initially thinking about making it a middleware function but I don't think that would eliminate the issue of a response going back to Plaid rather that react?

Comment: I think if you are trying to push to the client when the webhook has been fired - you can:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Plaid API documentation](https://plaid.com/docs/transactions/webhooks/#example-code-in-plaid-pattern) points to a [Plaid Pattern repo](https://github.com/plaid/pattern) as a code example for handling transaction webhooks. In the example, they use WebSockets (Socket.IO) to notify the front-end.

- [backend emit](https://github.com/plaid/pattern/blob/3414209a0b573eb5d96ab7ed900e633ce1c14db2/server/webhookHandlers/handleTransactionsWebhook.js#L164-L173)

```
const handleTransactionsWebhook = async (requestBody, io) => {
  const {
    webhook_code: webhookCode,
    item_id: plaidItemId,
    new_transactions: newTransactions,
    ...
  } = requestBody;

  const serverLogAndEmitSocket = (additionalInfo, itemId) => {
    console.log(
      `WEBHOOK: TRANSACTIONS: ${webhookCode}: Plaid_item_id ${plaidItemId}: ${additionalInfo}`
    );
    // use websocket to notify the client that a webhook has been received and handled
    if (webhookCode) io.emit(webhookCode, { itemId });
  };

  switch (webhookCode) {
    ...
    case 'HISTORICAL_UPDATE': {
      // Fired when an Item's historical transaction pull is completed. Plaid fetches as much
      // data as is available from the financial institution.
      const startDate = moment().subtract(2, 'years').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      const endDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      await handleTransactionsUpdate(plaidItemId, startDate, endDate);
      const { id: itemId } = await retrieveItemByPlaidItemId(plaidItemId);
      serverLogAndEmitSocket(`${newTransactions} transactions to add.`, itemId);
      break;
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

- [frontend handle event](https://github.com/plaid/pattern/blob/07d25d4fedc10559f9ba121a530739d77e9f26b4/client/src/components/Sockets.jsx#L37-L42)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = io(`localhost:${REACT_APP_SERVER_PORT}`);

    ...

    socket.current.on('HISTORICAL_UPDATE', ({ itemId } = {}) => {
      const msg = `New Webhook Event: Item ${itemId}: Historical Transactions Received`;
      console.log(msg);
      toast(msg);
      getTransactionsByItem(itemId, true);
    });
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30283531)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are trying to push to the client when the Webhook has been fired - you can:

1. Store the `res` object from the endpoint one (Not sure how you map the Webhook call to the initial request). Once the Webhook is fired, look up the `res` object and close the initial request. This is less than ideal. If the Webhook fails to fire before the initial request socket closes or if you need to scale your application - it won't scale as you will always need the Webhook to be called in the same app as where the open socket is referenced.
2. Use Websockets. Keep a persistent connection open to your client and push notifications on webhook invocation.